# Use launch image in Images.xcassets in UIImageView in Storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

The goal is to apply a blur and vibrancy effect to a launch image. Is this possible from Storyboard, or is it only possible programmatically? In other words, can you load an image from `Images.xcassets` in a UIImageView in Storyboard?

Comment: I think launch image is controlled by system so you do not have any control on it (by code). You can only make 'static' view in storyboard (eg. prepare your image with blur and add it to launch image view).

Comment: design your image with blur and vibrancy effcet and add the image in Images.xcassets use the image as launch image

Answer (score 0):

you can load image from Images.xcassets, but to give blur and vibrancy effect you need to code that.

OR you can create image with both effect and load it Images.xcassets

Answer (score 0):

You can setup your LaunchScreen storyboard with an UIImageView that load an image from `Images.xcassets` and a "Visual Effect Blur" or a "Visual Effect Views with Blur and Vibrancy" on top of it to apply the blur effect.
 The only "problem" is that the visual effect view has only the 3 type of blur provided (Light, Extra Light and Dark).

Answer (score 0):

Load  image resource from images.xcassets  and code the blur.

Or  you can use  add extension  `UIImage` to  blur, then add KeyPath in storyboard,that's  also running.

[image]